# display api data in the angular material table

Tags: angular, typescript, api, angular-material

I try to display data from a json file in the angular material table component but I can't.

**app.component.ts**

```
ELEMENT_DATA: Itype[];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['dechets.bouteille_plastique'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Itype>(this.ELEMENT_DATA); // probleme is here

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.getAllDetails();
  }

  public getAllDetails() {
    let resp = this.authService.getDetails();
    resp.subscribe(report => this.dataSource.data=report as Itype[])
  }
```

**interface**

```
export interface Itype {

    type_collecte: string;
    dechets: {
        bouteille_plastique: number;
    }
}
```

**json.file**

```
 {
        "type collecte": "reccurente",
        "dechets": {
            "bouteille_plastique": 2.9,
        },
    },
```

I don't know if I did it right in html

**html**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

        <!-- Position Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="dechets.bouteille_plastique">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Type de dechets</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.dechets.bouteille_plastique}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: What does "but I can't" mean? Do you get any error?

Comment: Property 'ELEMENT_DATA' is used before its initialization

Comment: Please edit your post and add the error message - see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by the comment you provided: "property 'ELEMENT_DATA' is used before its initialization", this means ELEMENT_DATA it's not initialized when it's used to define dataSource.

You just need to change the ELEMENT_DATA definition in the class to:

```
ELEMENT_DATA: IType[] = [];
```

In this way when the component get instantiated it can use the empty array as value to initialize the dataSource object.